# Use an object's "name" attribute as the visible option for select tag but pass its "id" to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User object that is formatted like:

`User(id: integer, email: string, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, school_id: integer)`

I also have an array of objects, `@schools` that all have attributes `name` and `id`

For the new User view, I would like to have a drop down menu that displays the name of the school (`@school.name`). I would like this drop down menu to pass the corresponding `@school.id` to the `Users`' controller to match the particular `id` of the school selected in the drop down menu with the new User's `school_id` attribute.

In my view, I have

```
<%= f.label :school_id %>
<%= f.select :school_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@schools, "id", "name") %>
```

however, whenever I purposefully put an error (such as having a password of 5 characters instead of the validation-specified 6), I get a `undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the most readable way to create a `select` using a db table is by using [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select)

```
<%= f.collection_select :school_id, @schools, :id, :name %>
```

If you want to use [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select)

```
<%= f.select :school_id, @schools.map { |school| [school.name, school.id] } %>
```